# LongClick not working on an empty gridview

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it possible to handle longclick on an empty gridview or on an empty place of gridview? I tried to use code shown below:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

    gridview.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "does it works?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

But, unfortunately, it doesn't work.
Could somebody tell me, how can I handle this event on an empty gridview?
Thanks

I attach also my xml file:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_margin="-5dip"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:numColumns="3" >
    </GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

GridView consists of views created from adapter. If you want to add LongClickListener you should use OnItemLongClickListener. I don't think there's any usefulness of using LongClickListener in GridView itself.

Comment: I'd like to show window "add a new element" after longclick. How could I solve it in your opinion?

Comment: First take a look into BaseAdapter, there are lots of example of Adapter you will find in the web. Once you have data in the GirdView, you can add OnItemCLickListener and OnItemLongClickListener in the GridView.

Answer (score 0):

The view is NULL, where you can setXXXListener ? so it can't .

Answer (score 0):

Let the gridview listen to the "`OnTouchListener`" , and use a `GestureDetector` to handle the `onTouch` event . Finally do what you want in the "`onLongPress`" method.

In addition,to avoid the conflict between the `onLongPress` and the `onItemLongclick` , we can check that is the item clicked or the empty place longPressed.

`int itemPosition = mGridView.pointToPosition((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());` , if itemPosition == -1 , it mean the empty place .